# How Update does work for iPhone App?

Tags: iphone

I would like to know how updates work for the Apple store.

Does Apple delete all the old data related to the old version of the application and then update to the newer one?

When a user updates to a new version of any application, does the older version get deleted from their iPhone with all data ( pictures, database, sound,etc) and get replaced by the newer version or not?

I updated my application a few days ago, and I think that Apple does not replace the old SQLITE database with the newer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During update old application bundle is replaced by the new one. All other folders and so their contents in application sandbox (Documents, Library, tmp) remain untouched.

So if you want to replace old database (if you must save data changed by users in old database) you just need to check database version in your app and copy the new one from application bundle if version is old (you can use sqlite [user_version](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version) pragma for version tracking)

Comment: how to do so in order to replace the old DataBase ( old.sqlite) by the newer one ( new.sqlite) .