# What precisely happens when iOS installs an update to an app?

Tags: iphone, xcode

What is the *official, documented* behavior when you install an update to an app?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325465/how-update-does-work-for-iphone-app) asks the same thing, but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325465/how-update-does-work-for-iphone-app/4325484#4325484), which says that the app bundle is replaced but all other folders are untouched, does not provide any documentation. I have [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206866/why-isnt-my-iphone-app-bundle-replacing-the-old-one-during-an-update) to believe that the app bundle, in fact, is *not* replaced, so I'd like to know for sure.

Please link to documentation!

Comment: As a followup on the question and answer. Middaparka's answer answers one part of the question - what files/data are preserved. I'm trying to figure out what delegate methods are called (if any) in the scenario like this: 1. We're on iOS 4.x with background processing ON
2. App goes to background (home button) - applicationWillResignActive: & applicationDidEnterBackground: are called
3. User opt to update from AppStore Is app killed? Is applicationWillTeminate: called? I guess (as the bundle is replaced) that app must be killed, right?

Comment: @Pavel, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139588/applicationwillterminate-in-ios-4-0

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW10) (see the "Files Saved During Application Updates" section within "The File System"):

> When a user downloads an application
>   update, iTunes installs the update in
>   a new application directory. It then
>   moves the user’s data files from the
>   old installation over to the new
>   application directory before deleting
>   the old installation. Files in the
>   following directories are guaranteed
>   to be preserved during the update
>   process:
>
> - `<Application_Home>/Documents`
> - `<Application_Home>/Library`
>
> Although
>   files in other user directories may
>   also be moved over, you should not
>   rely on them being present after an
>   update.

What you're seeing in the [Why isn't my iPhone app bundle replacing the old one during an update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206866/why-isnt-my-iphone-app-bundle-replacing-the-old-one-during-an-update) question is an issue where Xcode doesn't correctly detect/push updated resources to the device, which is a very different scenario.