# Is Game Update will store Existing information?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

whether a game update will  store the users details like score and levels unlocked,or else it will reset the game as new.

No i am developing a game with 10 levels and going to release it.another 10 levels will be given in as next version. At that time of update whether the old score will be stored or not.

Can any one help me for this Question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225974/what-precisely-happens-when-ios-installs-an-update-to-an-app

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store information such as score you should use NSUserdefaults.

Like:

```
NSUserDefaults *highscore = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int playerHighscore = [highscore integerForKey:@"playerHighscore"];
```