# Get notified at runtime when iOS App is about to being updated by iTunes or App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

Is there any way to receive notification *inside* a running iOS App when the OS is about to update the same App so it can release resources?

The problem we currently encounter with an App is that when updating the running App (i.e. replacing it with a newer version of the App) through iTunes then the process stalls and the previous version of the App remains active.

This *may* be due to the fact that the active App is playing audio in the background at that moment.

So ideally I'd like to release resources and stop the audio playback when an update process for that App is started. How do I do that?

Here's a rough sketch of what's happening AFAIK:

- App in version 1 is installed and running, playing back audio
- New version of the IPA (version 2) is added to iTunes
- App is set to update, Device is set to sync
- Start Update of *running* App from iTunes

Symptoms:

- App update starts
- After a short time the App's icon stalls / stays in the "Installing..." progress state
- App cannot be started via this stalled App icon
- Previous version of the App is still running (i.e. audio is still playing back)

If I first end the running App and then start the update through iTunes everything is just fine (of course...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think the fact that your application is running has nothing to do with app being installed.

> When a user downloads an application update, iTunes installs the
>   update in a new application directory. It then moves the user’s data
>   files from the old installation over to the new application directory
>   before deleting the old installation. Files in the following
>   directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process:

```
<Application_Home>/Documents
<Application_Home>/Library
```

> Although files in other user directories may also be moved over, you
>   should not rely on them being present after an update.

So basically it is a completely new app, just that your documents are preserved.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226037/919545

Comment: Ok, that makes sense and also explains why the background audio keeps running. The user has to manually close the running App, then the audio stops, then the icon of the App finishes the installing/loading animation. Finally, after that, tapping the App icon launches the updated version of the App.